# Azure CLI in python

Tags: python, azure, command-line-interface

I'm running some Azure CLI commands from a python program.

```
process = subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

command_list = "Connect-AzAccount \n" + "az keyvault secret show --vault-name " + vault_name + " --name " + secret_name
out, err = process.communicate(command_list.encode('utf-8'))
```

Is it possbile from this to see if something went wrong? like the user didn't logg in or the vault does not exist? It seems to be printing these error to the terminal but I would like to catch them in my program.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Azure SDK for Python?

Comment: Well i wanted the prompt that you get with "az login" and I could not find how to do that in the SDK. Or let the user login with user creds as you would with the prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually using a mixture of CLI and Azure PowerShell module.

I've tested on my machine thinking that it shouldn't matter, but it actually does.  If you login with PowerShell but execute a command with az.exe then you get:

```
Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

...which is exactly what you need to do to use Az.  So you have a choice.  You can either use PowerShell only (Az Module) and replace `az keyvault secret show --vault-name xxxx` with `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName xxxx`, az.exe only by replacing `Connect-AzAccount` with `az login`, or you could use both but you would need to log in to both.  My recommendation, since you're using pipes for interprocess communication, would be to use az.exe only.  But it really depends on the entirety of what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: I changed to use az.exe. However the error does not exist in out or err. It seems to just print to the terminal as "Please run 'az login' to setup account." while error stream is empty and ouput stream simply has the command i ran

Comment: First try changing powershell.exe to cmd.exe.  Second, try sending `az login` to process.communicate() first, followed by process.wait().  Hopefully that will pop the login prompt up for you.  Failing this, try using a service principal with az login instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest